Flutterflow Web Socket Integration
Has anyone successfully integrated web socket to Flutterflow? If so, can you please share the steps?
I've tried writing custom actions and functions obtained from claude cos I am not a flutter/Dart developer but it was like pulling teeth

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
